# Handle error in Swift 4.2 without downcasting error

Tags: swift, error-handling

I defined an error type called "HelloError", after multiple calls, I have to do downcast using **as!** and the error in do-catch block.

```
enum HelloError: Error {
    case A
    case B
}

func hello() throws {
    try helloAgain()
}

func helloAgain() throws {
    throw HelloError.A
}

do {
    try hello()
    } catch {
    switch error as! HelloError {
    case .A:
        print("A")
    case .B:
        print("B")
    }
}
```

Is it possible to catch the error without downcasting the error type? I want to write code like this:

```
do {
    try hello()
} catch {
    switch error {
    case HelloError.A:
        print("A")
    case HelloError.B:
        print("B")
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the *switch* with multiple `catch` blocks

```
do {
    try hello()
} catch HelloError.A {
     print("A")
} catch HelloError.B {
    print("B")
}
```

More detailed information is in [Swift Language Guide: Error handling](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ErrorHandling.html)